# parse JSON into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Hi I have big problem with parsing data. I have structure like this:

```
<code>
[{
    "absent": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "against":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "club": "club1",
    "for":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "withhold": ["a", "b", "c"]
}, {
    "absent": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "against":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "club": "club2",
    "for":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "withhold": ["a", "b", "c"]
}, {
    "absent": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "against":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "club": "club3",
    "for":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "withhold": ["a", "b", "c"]
}]
</code>
```

and I need parse this structure to array like this one:

```
<code>
    array={a,"absent",clube1
    b,absent,clube1
    c,absent,clube1
    a,against,clube1
    b,against,clube1
    c,against,clube1
    a,for,clube1
    b,for,clube1
    c,for,clube1
    a,withhold,clube1
    b,withhold,clube1
    c,withhold,clube1

    a,absent,clube2
    b,absent,clube2
    c,absent,clube2
    a,against,clube2
    b,against,clube2
    c,against,clube2
    a,for,clube2
    b,for,clube2
    c,for,clube2
    a,withhold,clube2
    b,withhold,clube2
    c,withhold,clube2
    }
</code>
```

etc... 
Can anybody help me ? I'm using pure Java Script. I can't change this structure so only one way it's write code for sort this out. Thanks for help and sorry for my English.

Comment: You forget to add the javascript code you tried so far!

Comment: Looks like something for [Array#reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), but where is your attempt and the problem?

Comment: Why doesn't your desired structure have quotes around the strings?

Comment: You need nested loops.

Comment: I tray to use this <code> var flattenObject = function(ob) {
 var toReturn = {};
 
 for (var i in ob) {
  if (!ob.hasOwnProperty(i)) continue;
  
  if ((typeof ob[i]) == 'object')
  {
   var flatObject = flattenObject(ob[i]);
   for (var x in flatObject) {
    if (!flatObject.hasOwnProperty(x)) continue;
    //if(x == "for")tempForAraay[i] = x;
    toReturn[i + '.' + x] = flatObject[x];
   }
  } else {
   toReturn[i] = ob[i];
  }
 }
 return toReturn;
 };</code> but i Have problem because I need mark name as vote and club

Comment: I tray to use this http://www.codesend.com/view/f6974fb7a68c13d0ce6c58b2a949c99a/ but i Have problem because I need to add all name(a,b,c) as vote(for,absent, against, withold) and club name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, it basically maps over the whole structure:

```
data.map((el) =>
    Object.keys(el)
        .filter((key) => key !== "club")
        .map((key) => el[key].map((v) => [v, key, el["club"]]))
).join()
```

For OP's other format:

```
data.map((el) =>
    Object.keys(el)
        .filter((key) => key !== "club")
        .map((key) => el[key].map((v) => [v, key, el["club"]]))
).reduce((arr, el) => arr.concat(el.reduce((x, a) => x.concat(a), [])), [])
```

Comment: You are AWESOM !! thanks !! Work perfect Culd you give me one more feedback? I give wrong structure,  how to change your code to give me structure as array not a String [0].name.vote.club Have a nice weekend Thanks!

Comment: If you mean having an array of arrays, where each array has three elements, the second one should work -- code is a little weird, might be a simpler way somehow :)

Comment: There is a problem with second code Uncaught TypeError: el[key].map is not a function. You are great ! Thanks for your support.

Comment: sorry my mistake WORKS PERFECT Thanks again !!

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [{
    "absent": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "against":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "club": "club1",
    "for":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "withhold": ["a", "b", "c"]
}, {
    "absent": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "against":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "club": "club2",
    "for":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "withhold": ["a", "b", "c"]
}, {
    "absent": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "against":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "club": "club3",
    "for":  ["a", "b", "c"],
    "withhold": ["a", "b", "c"]
}];

//console.log(arr);
var arr2 = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var ab = arr[i].absent;
    for (var key in arr[i]) {
        if (arr[i].hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            for(var j = 0; j < ab.length; j++) {
                arr2.push(ab[j], key, arr[i].club);
            }
        }
    }
}
//console.log("2: ", arr2);
```